# I cannot insert a space with spacebar

Tags: visual-studio-code

I cannot insert a space by pressing spacebar, instead I have to use shift+space. 
I tried changing the keyboard shortcut setting but still couldn't figure out how to change it back.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

alright I figured it out.
I accidentally assigned Add Selection To Next Find Match to Space. I deleted it and things got back to normal. 
I am happy again.